# Name of Young Adult novel from 1960s/ 70s with Harry Houdini?

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult

I'm looking for the title of a book I read as a kid in the 60s/70s. It's about a teenage boy who's fascinated with magic and Harry Houdini, and develops his magical powers with Houdini's help.

I just found the book ---Black and Blue Magic. It's about a 12 year old kid named after Harry Houdini, and he grows wings through use of a magic potion. I highly recommend this for young adults.

Answer (score 3):

The title is [Black and Blue Magic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/68765.Black_and_Blue_Magic) by Zilpha Keatley Snyder

> *"You'd think that someone with a name like Harry Houdini Marco would be deft and skillful, but Harry could only occasionally catch even an
>   easy fly ball without making some dumb error. On top of that, most of
>   his friends' families were moving to the suburbs. It would have been a
>   long, dreary summer, but then a Mr. Mazeeck showed up and turned out
>   to be more than he seemed."*

[image: Black and Blue Magic]

Comment: Congrats on finding it and thanks for sharing the answer!

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" your answer, so that the question doesn't show up as "unanswered".